# Find next occurrence without moving to it in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, find, phpstorm

Always when I press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> to search for something in my code, the viewport jumps to the next occurrence of the currently entered text as I type it and it is a bit confusing, because it jumps like 5 times till I finish typing. I'd like to not move the viewport, until I press <kbd>F3</kbd> to move to the next occurrence.

I tried to google it and found nothing useful. Also in keymap editor the only option was "find / move to the next occurrence" bound to <kbd>F3</kbd>, but no option for only "find".

Is it possible with some plugin or a bit of programming to change this behaviour?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to change this behaviour. Just in case, checked Registry for any non-documented setting but nothing related there as well.

Comment: On related note: consider voting/commenting on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124048

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah, this is exactly what I am looking for, but I don't see any vote or comment button...

Comment: Did you register/logged in there? You have to be. It's a public tracker so anyone can register. Once you are in, look for the thumb up icon for votes, comments are below. https://postimg.cc/t1FcYYpD

Comment: @LazyOne I thought that everyone can vote, not just the logged in users. Anyway, I'm definitely going to vote for this suggestion. Thanks for letting me know. :D